# Looking for a closed form sum of a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am wondering if there is a closed form solution of the following series
$$
2 \sum_{n =1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (\pi  a n) }{\pi  n} (1-\cos (\pi  n)) \exp \left(-(\pi  a n)^2 t^{2 b}\right)
$$
where $0\leq b\leq 1$, $0<a<1$ and $0 \le t $.

Thanks

Comment: this is more or less the Fourier series coefficients of $f(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{-(t-k)^2}$. do you know how to show it ?

Comment: No I do n't, I will look into it, but I will also appreciate If you can show me, it will be educational for me.